# Populate ComboBox with File Names from Online Directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I am trying for days to populate a ComboBox with the names of files in a directory that is stored on my server online but getting nowhere.

Here is the code I am using. I am not getting any errors or anything but nothing is appearing in the combobox. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

```
        Try
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Australia" Then
            ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("ChartCountries\Australia.txt"))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "FS Enhancer")
    End Try
    'Load Charts
    Try
        If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "Bendigo (YBDG)" Then
            Dim sf As String
            For Each sf In Directory.GetFiles(My.Settings.ChartsURL & "AU/Bendigo/")
                ComboBox3.Items.Add(sf)
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "FS Enhancer")
    End Try
```

Thanks in advance.

Update:
Have given the code below 'Load Charts its own function. Also changed the code as well to below. But getting "URI Formats Not Accepted"

```
        'Load Charts
    Try
        If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "Bendigo (YBDG)" Then
            Dim dir = My.Settings.ChartsURL & "/AU/Bendigo"
            For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(dir)
                ComboBox3.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
            Next

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "FS Enhancer")
    End Try
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have those 2 imports Imports System
Imports System.IO

Comment: Hi phil652, Yes I have.

Comment: `My.Settings.ChartsURL & "AU/Bendigo/")` <- are you sure this is valid?

Comment: @Mort Yes, The URL to the main directory is in My.Settings then /AU/Bendigo/ and the PDF files are in /Bendigo/

Comment: So you're not missing that extra "/" somewhere in the mix? Does a Dorectory.Exists return true too ?

Comment: @Mort Yes, the URL, for example is http://www.sample.com/directory with a / at the end That is how it is in My.Settings. So the remainder is AU/Bendigo/file.pdf

Comment: Getting there slowly. Gave the code below 'Load Charts its own function and changed it as well. Now getting "URI Formats Not Accepted" Have edited code above.

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` works only on the local file system.  You can't pass a URL.  It doesn't know anything about the internet.  That's what FTP is for.

Comment: But I don't want to download the file. I just want the file name to show in a ComboBox. Surely I won't need FTP access for that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is interested, I managed to get this to work.

I first placed all the countries into the first ComboBox using a Collection String. I then uploaded a txt file called, in this example, "Australia" to the server with City names inside.

```
            Try
        lstAirports.Items.Clear()
        If lstCountries.SelectedItem = "Australia" Then
            Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
            Dim country As String = client.DownloadString(My.Settings.ChartURL & "Australia.rc")
            Dim lines As String() = country.Split(New String() {ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            lstAirports.Items.AddRange(lines)
        End If End Try
```

Airport Names:

```
         If lstAirports.SelectedItem = "Melbourne (YMML)" Then
            Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
            Dim country As String = client.DownloadString(My.Settings.ChartURL & "Charts/AU/YMML.rc")
            Dim lines As String() = country.Split(New String() {ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            lblAboutAirport.Text = "About " & lstAirports.Text
            txtBoxAirport.Text = "Melbourne Airport, also known as Tullamarine Airport, is the primary airport serving the city of Melbourne, and the second busiest airport in Australia. It was opened in 1970 to replace the nearby Essendon Airport" & vbNewLine & "The airport is 23 km (14 mi) from the city centre. The airport has its own postcode, which is Melbourne Airport, Victoria, 3045. This is adjacent to the suburb of Tullamarine."
            lstCharts.Items.AddRange(lines)
        End If
```

I then uploaded another file that contained the names of the Charts for an airport in that area and called that into a Third ComboBox:

```
         If lstCharts.SelectedItem = "YMML Aerodrome 1" Then
            AxAcroPDF1.src = My.Settings.ChartURL & "Charts/AU/Melbourne/Aerodrome1.pdf #toolbar=0&navpanes=0"
        End If
        If lstCharts.SelectedItem = "YMML Aerodrome 2" Then
            AxAcroPDF1.src = My.Settings.ChartURL & "Charts/AU/Melbourne/Aerodrome2.pdf #toolbar=0&navpanes=0"
        End If
```

So clicking on the name of the Chart in the third ComboBox displays the Chart in the PDF Reader.